# How can I visually identify which board revision I have?

Tags: hardware, revision

[This question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/which-board-do-i-have) asks about using `/proc/cpuinfo` to identify the revision of the board I have.

Are there any visual characteristics that differentiate between the different board revisions?

Comment: I like how people who found this useful, never forgot to upvote the question too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wikipedia has a [good graphical summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Connectors) of the various board designs:

Raspberry Pi 1 model A+ revision 1.1: [image: Raspberry Pi 1 model A+ revision 1.1]

Raspberry Pi 1 model B and B+ revision 1.2: [image: Raspberry Pi 1 model B+ revision 1.2, and Raspberry Pi 2 model B]

The Raspberry Pi 1 model B revision 2: [image: Raspberry Pi 1 model B revision 2]

The Revision 2 board has holes for an additional header next to the main header P1 and also there are now mounting holes.

[image: Revision 2 Highlights]

Comment: What differences are there for earlier revisions, which seem to include: Raspberry Pi Model B Revision 1.0 and 1.1; and A+ Revision 1.0 and may be others - what would someone getting a second-hand one on a global auction site use to confirm what was being offered?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/blog/2016/11/21/how-to-identify-which-model-of-the-raspberry-pi-you-have nice overview showing also rpi 3 vs rpi 2

Comment: This  link is only accessible to registered users :-(

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Board revision is not printed on PCB. You can, however, easily check if you have the latest (right now) revision  - it has mounting holes and older ones did not have them. It also has "made in UK" text written while older ones did not have them. If Foundation make some other future revisions, you won't be able to differentiate them in such easy way.