# Which model Raspberry Pi I am running?

Tags: pi-2, pi-3, wifi, bash

Is there a way of determining whether the current Raspberry Pi is either a **2 Model B** and **3** with **Raspbian Jessie Lite 8.0**?

This is because I have a particular `bootstrap.sh` written in Bash where it needs to set the attribute `txpower` for a Wi-Fi USB dongle (here, Raspberry Pi 2) using a **Ralink RT5370 chipset** driver.

I set the Wireless attributes using `iwconfig` (which, I know is deprecated, but it currently gets the job done, so I am not changing it).

Since, in **Raspberry Pi 3** the internal Wi-Fi chipset is a `bcm`-based chipset which will not let the following command execute:

```
iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc channel 6 essid myadhoc txpower 0dBm
```

With Raspberry Pi 3 the above mentioned command works just by removing `dBm` from the above mentioned command:

```
iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc channel 6 essid myadhoc txpower 0
```

I would like to add a check whether the Raspberry Pi model is 2 or 3 using Bash.

Any hints?

In case, someone wants to go through the `bootstrap.sh`: [Bootstrapping for TWIN](https://github.com/ComNets-Bremen/TWIN/blob/master/bootstrap.sh)

## Notes

- I checked that `dBm` is *not required*, also in the case of the **Raspberry Pi 2** with the **Ralink chipset** hence for non-ambiguity one can use the same command for *both the Raspberry Pis* viz.

  ```
  iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc channel 6 essid myadhoc txpower 0
  ```
- It is interesting to note that for **external Wi-Fi USB dongles** one needs to perform the following (for **Raspberry Pi 2**):

  ```
  ifconfig wlan0 down
  iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc channel 6 essid myadhoc txpower 0
  ifconfig wlan0 up
  ```

  while as for **inbuilt Wi-Fi modules (Raspberry Pi 3)** there is *no need* for `ifconfig up and down`. Just the straightforward `iwconfig` command works.

Comment: The best approach is to test for the thing you want to do instead of looking for models (how will the Raspberry Pi 5 look like?).  In this case, see if there is a Ralink RT5370 Chipset and configure accordingly.  Same way with the built in Wifi driver.

Comment: Related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1826/19949

Comment: related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/100076/19949

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What OS version is installed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85015/what-os-version-is-installed)

Comment: cat /proc/cpuinfo

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
cat /proc/device-tree/model
```

returns something like

```
Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
```

Comment: This still works perfectly in March 2022. It returns `Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W Rev 1.0` on my, well, Pi Zero 2 W.

Answer (score 24):

## By CPU Type

You could check the RPi version with the command, `uname`. The different RPi versions have different CPU architectures. The RPi 2 has an arm7, whereas the 3 has an arm8.

```
uname -m
```

## By Hardware Revision

If you need to be more specific, you can check the *revision* entry from the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. If you want to just exact the revision number, the following command should do it:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'Revision' | awk '{print $3}'
```

### Revision Numbers

[This webpage](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/09/checking-your-raspberry-pi-board-version/) has a handy chart that I've copied here.

[image]

Comment: I went through `/proc/cpuinfo` before. It seems like the best option, since `uname -m` does not tell much.

Comment: @Shan-Desai: not sure if you saw it, before the edit, but I just included a command that will extract just the revision information from the proc file. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yup I tried the one you mentioned. The comparison was between a __Pi 2 Model v1.1__ and __Pi 3 Model B__ the funny thing however is that my __Pi 3__ still shows __armv7l__ upon `uname -m`

Comment: You mean /proc/cpuinfo not /cpu/procinfo

Comment: `uname` will only list the target architecture linux was built for, and is unreliable for determining the CPU Type. Current RPI3 Raspbian runs in 32 bit mode. it will list `armv7`, if you use an `AARCH64` (`arm64`) linux it will say  `armv8`, if you use the old RPI1 raspbian it will say `armv6`.

Comment: A little update the Foundation has all the current revision codes listed here https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/revision-codes/README.md including those that are newer than this answer.

Comment: @Ghanima I want to put the revised list that is shown on the rasperrypi.org link here - should I post a new answer or edit this answer? I think an answer update might be more reasonable. On the other hand anyone interested in it can see the link.

Comment: @user3123159 Stackexchange certainly encourages users to post separate answers if they (the users) think that another answer would be a valuable contribution. The decission is all yours, feel free to post an answer - it would be more prominent than just a comment burried under another answer. On a personal note, Jacob had his chance to incorporate this additional information in his answer ;-)

Answer (score 11):

There are many methods (of varying reliability) to determine this.
One of the most complete and reliable is `gpio -v` which produces the following output.

```
gpio version: 2.44
Copyright (c) 2012-2017 Gordon Henderson
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type: gpio -warranty

Raspberry Pi Details:
  Type: Pi 3, Revision: 02, Memory: 1024MB, Maker: Embest 
  * Device tree is enabled.
  *--> Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
  * This Raspberry Pi supports user-level GPIO access.
```

This could be done more elegantly by writing a simple program, using the functions provided by `wiringpi`. These are well documented, and the source is readily available.

> The script in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/85016/8697 shows comprehensive information **about** your Pi and OS.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough rep to comment on @Andy Delgado reply but heres a different version of his code using some newer bash features.

```
function check_pi_version() {
  local -r REVCODE=$(awk '/Revision/ {print $3}' /proc/cpuinfo)
  local -rA REVISIONS=(
    [0002]="Model B Rev 1, 256 MB RAM"
    [0003]="Model B Rev 1 ECN0001, 256 MB RAM"
    [0004]="Model B Rev 2, 256 MB RAM"
    [0005]="Model B Rev 2, 256 MB RAM"
    [0006]="Model B Rev 2, 256 MB RAM"
    [0007]="Model A, 256 MB RAM"
    [0008]="Model A, 256 MB RAM"
    [0009]="Model A, 256 MB RAM"
    [000d]="Model B Rev 2, 512 MB RAM"
    [000e]="Model B Rev 2, 512 MB RAM"
    [000f]="Model B Rev 2, 512 MB RAM"
    [0010]="Model B+, 512 MB RAM"
    [0013]="Model B+, 512 MB RAM"
    [900032]="Model B+, 512 MB RAM"
    [0011]="Compute Module, 512 MB RAM"
    [0014]="Compute Module, 512 MB RAM"
    [0012]="Model A+, 256 MB RAM"
    [0015]="Model A+, 256 MB or 512 MB RAM"
    [a01041]="2 Model B v1.1, 1 GB RAM"
    [a21041]="2 Model B v1.1, 1 GB RAM"
    [a22042]="2 Model B v1.2, 1 GB RAM"
    [90092]="Zero v1.2, 512 MB RAM"
    [90093]="Zero v1.3, 512 MB RAM"
    [0x9000C1]="Zero W, 512 MB RAM"
    [a02082]="3 Model B, 1 GB RAM"
    [a22082]="3 Model B, 1 GB RAM"
  )

  echo "Raspberry Pi ${REVISIONS[${REVCODE}]} (${REVCODE})"
}
```

Aside: `REVISIONS` is defined inside of a function since I use it over `ssh` i.e. `ssh some-host "$(declare -f); check_pi_version"`

Comment: There is an error with the leading `0` in `0008` and `0009` as it is interpreted as an octal number I think.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use tool called `pinout`

[image]

Comment: Whilst this might be a great tool, your answer doesn't meet the guidelines for  what an answer requires. Please update it with details on how to install the tool and the command to run to get this response. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I created a bash script that will provide the model info based on the Revision.

If you make it better, please let me know.

```
#!/bin/bash
# which_pi.bash
# BASH Script to display Pi Hardware version based on info found in /proc/cpuinfo
# Andy Delgado - April 11, 2017
# Info gleaned from
# http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/09/checking-your-raspberry-pi-board-version

REVCODE=$(sudo cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'Revision' | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed 's/ *$//g')

if [ "$REVCODE" = "0002" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 1, 256 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "0003" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 1 ECN0001, 256 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "0004" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2, 256 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "0005" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2, 256 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "0006" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2, 256 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "0007" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model A, 256 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "0008" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model A, 256 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "0009" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model A, 256 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "000d" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2, 512 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "000e" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2, 512 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "000f" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2, 512 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "0010" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model B+, 512 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "0013" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model B+, 512 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "900032" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model B+, 512 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "0011" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Compute Module, 512 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "0014" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Compute Module, 512 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "0012" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model A+, 256 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "0015" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Model A+, 256 MB or 512 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "a01041" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.1, 1 GB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "a21041" ]; then
    # a21041 (Embest, China)
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.1, 1 GB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "a22042" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.2, 1 GB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "90092" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Zero v1.2, 512 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "90093" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Zero v1.3, 512 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "0x9000C1" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi Zero W, 512 MB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "a02082" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, 1 GB RAM"
fi

if [ "$REVCODE" = "a22082" ]; then
    PIMODEL="Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, 1 GB RAM"
fi

echo "$PIMODEL ($REVCODE)"
```

Comment: An else if structure would be far more efficient.

Comment: A switch statement would be better.

Answer (score -2):

Simple way : `dmesg | grep "Machine model:"`

Comment: Strange, this doesn't output anything when I try it!

Comment: @goldilocks Displays `[Tue Apr 11 15:59:32 2017] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2` on my Pi. May not be the most robust method.

Comment: @Milliways The reason it doesn't do this for me is the system has been up too long.  That's from boot, and `dmesg` is a circular buffer.  *Hence, this is a flawed methodology.*

Comment: @goldilocks Presumably the OP only wants to know after boot. It is unlikely to change ;-) There are almost certainly better methods of solving OP problem.

Comment: the best solution in my opinion. works perfectly on Raspberry Pi 2 and 3, running Raspbian. I have tested it on a Pi that runs since 8 days. The other solutions in this thread required either new tools (gpio) or you have to map the cpu revision code to a look-up table (and maintain it). that's the only command which tells you exactly the name i.e. `Machine model: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.1` - without root too.