# How does Raspbian know it's been installed in a Pi or Compute Module?

Tags: raspbian, python-3

I want to design a python script that would allow me to check whether it's currently in a standard Pi 3 or it's in a Compute Module 3. But I have no idea even on how Raspbian OS know itself is currently in a Pi 3 or a CM3.

Any help?

Comment: Related of not a dupe: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/61699/19949

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command is:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

And the list over the different hardware is here: http://elinux.org/RPi_HardwareHistory#Board_Revision_History

Table over hardware differences: https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/blog/2016/11/21/how-to-identify-which-model-of-the-raspberry-pi-you-have

Comment: Hi, thank you! I'll read through the information and try to utilize them in my codes. Thanks!

Comment: Chris Hager has a nice python script to do exactly this at https://github.com/metachris/raspberrypi-utils

Comment: @RickleusB.H.Yoon please mark one of the answers as "The answer"

Comment: @bobstro I think this covers more recent versions as well https://github.com/AndrewFromMelbourne/raspberry_pi_revision

Answer (score 0):

I have this script that show what Pi you have and its relevant data.
However I do not have all possible RPi's so a 100% test is not possible.
Still it may be of some use.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start WhichPi"



rev=$(grep Revision /proc/cpuinfo | cut -f 2 -d: | tr -d '[:space:]')
echo $rev
case $rev in
        0002)
            echo " A RPi B Rev 1.0 with 256MB RAM   Released: Q1 2012"
            ;;
        0003)
        echo "A RPi B Rev 1.0 (ECN0001 - no fuses , D14 removed with  256MB RAM   Released: Q3 2012"
            ;; 
        0004)
            echo "A RPi B Rev 2.0 with  256MB RAM   Released: Q3 2012 Manfacturer: Sony"
            ;;
        0005)
            echo "A RPi B Rev 2.0 with  256MB RAM   Released: Q3 2012 Manufacturer: Qisda "
            ;;

        0006)
            echo "A RPi B Rev 2.0 with  256MB RAM   Released: Q4 2012 Manufaturer Egoman"
            ;;
        0007)
            echo "A RPi A Rev 2.0 with  256MB RAM   Released: Q1 2013 Manfacturer: Egoman"
            ;;
        0008)
            echo "A RPi A Rev 2.0 with  256MB RAM   Released: Q1 2013 Manufacturer: Sony "
            ;;

        0009)
            echo "A RPi A Rev 2.0 with  256MB RAM   Released: Q1 2013 Manufaturer Qisda"
            ;;
        000d)
            echo "A RPi B Rev 2.0 with  512MB RAM   Released: Q4 2012 Manfacturer: Egoman"
            ;;            
        000e)
            echo "A RPi B Rev 2.0 with  512MB RAM   Released: Q4 2012 Manfacturer: Sony"
            ;;            
        000f)
            echo "A RPi B Rev 2.0 with  512MB RAM   Released: Q4 2012 Manfacturer: Qisda"
            ;;            
        0010)
            echo "A RPi B+ Rev 1.0 with  512MB RAM   Released: Q3 2014 Manfacturer: Sony"
           ;;
        0011)
            echo "A RPi Compute Module Rev 1.0 with  512MB RAM   Released: Q4 2014 Manfacturer: Sony"
            ;;            
        0012)
            echo "A RPi A+ Rev 1.1 with  256MB RAM   Released: Q4 2012 Manfacturer: Sony"
            ;;            
        0013)
            echo "A RPi B+ Rev 1.2 with  512MB RAM   Released: Q1 2015 Manfacturer: ?"
            ;;            
        0014)
            echo "A RPi Compute Module Rev 1.0 with  512MB RAM   Released: Q2 2014 Manfacturer: Embesty"
            ;;            
        0015)
            echo "A RPi A+ Rev 1.1 with  256MB/512MB RAM   Released: ? Manfacturer: Embesty"
            ;;            
       a01040)
            echo "A RPi 2 Model B Rev 1.0 with  1GB   Released: ? Manufacturer : ?"
            ;;            

       a01041)
            echo "A RPi 2 Model B Rev 1.1 with  1GB RAM   Released: Q1 2015 Manfacturer: Sony"
            ;;            
       a21041)
            echo "A RPi 2 Medel B  Rev 1.1 with 1GB RAM   Released: Q1 2015 Manfacturer: Embest"
            ;;            
       a22042)
            echo "A RPi 2 Model B (with BMC2837  Rev 1.2 with  1GB RAM   Released: Q3 2016 Manfacturer: EMbest"
            ;;            
       a02082)
            echo "A RPi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 with  1GB RAM   Released: Q1 2016 Manfacturer: Sony"
            ;;            
       a22082)
            echo "A RPi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 with  1GB RAM   Released: Q1 2016 Manfacturer: Embest"
            ;;            

       *)
            echo "BuM--"$rev"--"
            ;;



esac
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! it's working! But in my case, I've to say sorry to you mate, the team is preferring the `cat /proc/cpuinfo` method