# Is this a real raspberry pi 3 B or is it counterfeit?

Tags: official-foundation

Is this a real raspberry pi 3 B or is it counterfeit?

Hello,

I recently purchased what I believed was a Raspberry Pi 3 B. Now I am suspicious that it may not be.

lscpu shows as below. But Raspberry Pi 3 B is supposed to have armv8, no?

```
Architecture:          armv7l
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
Model:                 4
Model name:            ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
CPU max MHz:           1200.0000
CPU min MHz:           600.0000
BogoMIPS:              38.40
Flags:                 half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
```

Also, the sticker on the board says Raspberry Pi 3 B Copyright 2015. But the RPi3B was released in 2016, no?

Is there a way to confirm if this is a real RPi3B or a counterfeit unit? The box says 3B and there is some kind of 7 digit reference number if I can check that somewhere.

Vesa

[image]

Comment: Related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/61699/19949

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little confusing, your Raspberry Pi is `armv8` however, it is being run in `armv7` compatibility mode. This is determined by the OS.

In particular, `armv8` has a 64 bit architecture known as `AArch64` or `ARM64`
, it also has an execution mode that is compatible with `armv7`. Also known as `AArch32` or `A32`

Because 32 bit architecture of `armv8` is directly compatible with `armv7`, and for other technical reasons I am likely overlooking, the operating system refers to the arch as `armv7`

If you need further convincing. Raspbian *has a 64bit build*. that will report `armv8`.

For more information about using the 64 bit `armv8` architecture I will leave these links

- [Raspberry Pi Kernel Fork](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux)
- [Pi64  - 64Bit Debian Release for RPI](https://github.com/bamarni/pi64)
- [Tutorial to build 64 bit release from scratch](https://devsidestory.com/build-a-64-bit-kernel-for-your-raspberry-pi-3/)

Comment: Raspbian hasn't got a 64bit build. Those are other distros without foundation support.

Answer (score 2):

Under [Devuan](https://devuan.org)-1 for PI3 this looks like:

```
~$ lscpu
Architecture:          aarch64
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
CPU max MHz:           1200.0000
CPU min MHz:           600.0000
~$ head -8 /proc/cpuinfo 
processor       : 0
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : fp asimd evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4
```

...so misdiagnosing the CPU probably is caused by the OS and/or tools you run.

Comment: Misdiagnosing the CPU? Sounds unlikely. Using Rasbian like everyone else.

Comment: Think of it like running DOS in real mode on today's Intel chips. DOS's tools would not see the features added to today's CPUs simply because the tools don't look for it. Running Raspbian which still is compatible with the 1st PIs on a PI3 will run tools compatible with the 1st PI's 32bit CPU. The word "misdiagnosing" may not be the luckiest choice, but take into account that I'm not born with an english tounge. I hope these lines clarify what I meant good enough.

Comment: "Using Rasbian like everyone else."?!?! I always knew I'm not everyone else... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That is fine.

For reference the output of my Pi3B.

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          armv7l
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
Model name:            ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
CPU max MHz:           1200.0000
CPU min MHz:           600.0000



$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor   : 1
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor   : 2
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor   : 3
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : a02082
Serial      : 00000000bb786d6b
```

Comment: But why is it ARMv7? Isn't it supposed to be v8?

Comment: @Vesa I don't know, and neither do I care.  It does not mean the Pi is a counterfeit.

Comment: The core (for later Pi2 and All Pi3)  is `ARMv8`, but is running in `ARMv7` compatibility mode. The reporting is expected since raspbian release is still targeting 32 bit mode.