# What Pi Model & OS version is installed

Tags: linux, pi-models

Users often seem confused about what Pi model they have and what OS version is installed or how to find details.

Where is this located?

Comment: For a short simple answer see: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/101307/5538

Comment: @goldilocks: Yes, too bad it's closed... perhaps that answer could be moved here?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54806912#54806912

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following script is one I use including the following commands to collect relevant details. (It is called **aboutpi**)

Download latest from https://github.com/Milliways2/Raspberry-Pi-Utilities/blob/main/aboutpi

```bash
#! /bin/sh
# 2024-01-30    No LSB modules are available.
# Function to print coloured headings
#  delete "tput" lines for plain output
print_head () {
 tput setaf 6
 echo $1
 tput sgr 0
}

if [ -e /etc/rpi-issue ]; then
 print_head "- Original Installation"
 cat /etc/rpi-issue | grep reference
fi

if [ -e /usr/bin/lsb_release ]; then
 print_head "- Current OS"
 lsb_release -irdc | sed 's/No LSB modules are available.//'
 cat /etc/debian_version
fi
if [ ! -e /usr/share/xsessions ]; then
    print_head "X NOT installed"
fi
print_head "- Kernel"
uname -r
print_head "- Architecture"
uname -m

print_head "- Model"
cat /proc/device-tree/model && echo

print_head "- hostname"
hostname
print_head "- Network"
hostname -I

# Check status of networking
checkactive () {
if [ $(systemctl is-active $1) = 'active' ]; then
    echo $1 'active'
fi
}
checkactive 'systemd-networkd'
checkactive 'dhcpcd'
checkactive 'NetworkManager'

# Get SSID of connected WiFi (WRONG if AP!)
if [ -e /sys/class/net/wlan0 ]; then
    if [ $(systemctl is-active 'NetworkManager') = 'active' ]; then
        nmcli connection show |  awk '/wlan0/ {print $1}'
    else
        wpa_cli -i wlan0 status | grep -w ssid | awk -F'[=]' '{print $2}'
    fi
fi

sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0 | grep "Disk identifier"

CPUID=$(awk '/Serial/ {print $3}' /proc/cpuinfo | cut -c 9-)
# CPUID=$(vcgencmd otp_dump | grep 28: | cut -c4-)
echo "Serial: " $CPUID
if [ -e /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd -o /usr/bin/vcgencmd ]; then
#   VERS=$(vcgencmd version  | grep ":")
    VERS=$(sudo vcgencmd version  | grep ":")
    print_head "- Firmware"
    echo $VERS
fi
print_head "- Created"
sudo tune2fs -l $(mount -v | awk '/ on \/ / {print $1}') | grep created
```

---

To list the **initial installation** (Raspbian only)    `cat /etc/rpi-issue | grep reference`

```
Raspberry Pi reference 2019-06-20
```

To list the **Current OS**  `lsb_release -irdc`

```
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

To list the **Kernel version**  `uname -r`

```
4.19.58-v7l+
```

To list the **Model**   `cat /proc/device-tree/model`

Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1

> There are a number of other **interesting data**:-

To list the **hostname**    `hostname`

```
MilliwaysPi4
```

To list the **Firmware**    `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd version`

```
Jul  9 2019 14:37:58 
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version d2b1b7fb01475cb3914b2086299e32d724e832f1 (clean) (release) (start)
```

To list the **date the File System was "created"**  `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mmcblk0p2 | grep created` (only for Raspbian on SD Card, but could be modified for other)

```
Filesystem created:       Fri Jun 21 03:05:22 2019
```

---

Output on Raspberry Pi OS (64bit) Pi4B

```
- Original Installation
Raspberry Pi reference 2022-01-28
- Current OS
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:    11
Codename:   bullseye
11.7
- Kernel
6.1.21-v8+
- Architecture
aarch64
- Model
Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1
- hostname
MilliwaysPi4
- Network
10.1.2.74 10.1.2.84 
NetworkManager active
WiFi-B13A
Disk identifier: 0x2f89a8c6
Serial:  46c9fdae
- Firmware
Mar 17 2023 10:50:39
- Created
Filesystem created:       Fri Jan 20 12:46:02 2023
```

Output on Raspberry Pi OS Pi3B

```
- Original Installation
Raspberry Pi reference 2021-10-30
- Current OS
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:    11
Codename:   bullseye
11.6
- Kernel
6.1.21-v7+
- Architecture
armv7l
- Model
Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3
- hostname
MilliwaysPi3p
- Network
10.1.2.88 
dhcpcd active
WiFi-B13A-5G
Disk identifier: 0xff635d64
Serial:  519c72e8
- Firmware
Mar 17 2023 10:52:42
- Created
Filesystem created:       Sun Jan 29 12:34:01 2023
```

The output on my Pi3A+ shows

```
- Original Installation
Raspberry Pi reference 2021-10-30
- Current OS
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:    11
Codename:   bullseye
11.6
X NOT installed
- Kernel
6.1.21-v7+
- Architecture
armv7l
- Model
Raspberry Pi 3 Model A Plus Rev 1.0
- hostname
MilliwaysPi3A
- Network
10.1.2.93 
systemd-networkd active
WiFi-B13A
Disk identifier: 0xb5d2de0f
Serial:  f4e430a6
- Firmware
Mar 17 2023 10:52:42
- Created
Filesystem created:       Sat Aug  8 04:32:43 2020
```

Comment: Reminds me of the old SysInternals windows program **bginfo** - tempted to create a little Python program to hack the desktop :-). Bookmarked.

Answer (score 3):

A "quick and dirty" answer to the question follows. All can be entered from the command line interface:

1. `cat /etc/os-release` # provides NAMES, VERSIONS & some URLs for support
2. `lsb_release -a` # distribution-specific information; ref `man lsb_release`
3. `hostnamectl` # brief & useful incl hostname, OS ver, kernel ver; ref `man hostnamectl`

And as if you needed more, this command provides a terse summary with several options to get a specific item - which is useful in scripts to check version dependencies, etc. See `man uname` for details, and for example, the kernel version can be had as follows:

4. `uname -r`

---

Credits to [nixCraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-check-os-version-in-linux-command-line/) for the most complete answer I could find.