# Pi screen freezing and board getting warm with LoRa

Tags: pi-3, pi-2

<strike>I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and a RPi 2 for testing [these](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3072) two LoRa modules. I'm having a couple issues...</strike>  **SEE BELOW FOR UPDATED ISSUE**

1. **RPi screen freezes** - Whenever I try to test the modules with example code in [this](https://github.com/hallard/RadioHead) library, the screens freeze on both of the Pis.
2. **RPi Broadcom SoC chip heats up** - After the screen freezes, the board gets warmer than it is when the Pi is working fine, which I'm not sure if it's because a large process is going on in the background of if the LoRa is drawing more current after I end the process.
3. **RPi USB ports lose power** - Sometimes this happens before the screen freezes, but a lot of times it's after. I also lose access to ssh/vnc at this point, probably because the WiFi/Ethernet modules lose power also.

What I've tried so far to remedy this:

1. **Replacing power supply** - Number 3 above made me think the power supply was not enough, so I replaced it with a 5.2v 2.4A power supply and that did nothing. I also tried powering the LoRa modules with an external supply that was not linked to the Pi - that also did nothing.
2. **Replacing Pi** - I had an extra Pi 3 on hand and I replaced it with the other Pi 3, to no avail.

I'm thinking the issue may be software related, because when I began testing, my Pi 2 had an older version of Raspbian and I had fewer to no issues.

Occasionally, things run fine on 1 out of the 2 Pis, although the other one still crashes (after the screen freezes, the LoRa continues transmitting for ~10 seconds).

I'm stuck, so any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I rolled back my version of Raspbian to 4.9.80 and it started working perfectly - no issues.
However, I don't want to be running an old version of Raspbian on my project!
Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Welcome. A note about nomenclature: There is no such thing as Raspbian 4.9.80.  The first version of Raspbian was 7.0 (aka Wheezy), because the numbering follows the [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) distribution from which it is derived.  Since then there has been an 8.0 (aka Jessie) and 9.0 (aka Stretch).  "4.9.80" looks instead like a *Linux kernel version*; Linux is the OS kernel used.  You might want to explain exactly how you did this rollback of the kernel.

Comment: Thank you @goldilocks . Sorry about that, my Linux kernel version is 4.9.80. I rolled back my Pis by looking back into Hexxeh's rpi-firmware library and used rpi-update to roll back to an older version of the kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find which OS you have with `lsb_release -irc` see [About](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/85016/8697)

You have probably run `rpi-update`

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`
will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode.

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
>   Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

To get the latest Raspbian **ALL** you need to do is run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
```

"dist-upgrade will replace deprecated packages, upgrade will just update things that are already installed."

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I had run rpi-update and it appears that that was the issue, as the problem is non-existent as of now. Thanks for the detailed description of my problem and clarification on updating my pi