# How to upgrade raspbian stretch to latest release version

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I have a raspbian stretch image which is of release date `2018-03-13`. Is there any command I can use to upgrade it to the latest release os image of `raspbian`. I tried with `apt dist-upgrade` but the release date was same. I am checking the release date using `cat /boot/issue.txt`.

Is there any command available which I can you to upgrade the raspbian os image to its latest release version.

Thanks

Comment: `/boot/issue.txt` doesn't get updated when using `apt` - as long as you `apt update` and `apt upgrade` you should have the latest - note, my `/boot/issue.txt` has `Raspberry Pi reference 2016-05-27` ... because that's when I first flashed this pi (it was jessie back then)

Comment: Okay so after `dist-upgrade`, I can assume that its now updated to the latest available.? I have device connected at remote side so cannot flash card so just want to make sure  its updated to latest release. Is there any other way I can make sure its update to latest release.? Thanks

Comment: `uname -a` will show you the kernel version - `cat /etc/debian_version` should show 9.6 - not sure if that's at all useful

Comment: There are a  number of different significant OS dates - the script in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/85016/8697 shows you everything you might need.

Answer (score 1):

With `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` you will upgrade the system by removing/installing/upgrading packages. That's the option defined for `apt`. I don't know if `dist-upgrade` from `apt-get` do exactly the same. In `man apt` you can read:

> full-upgrade performs the function of upgrade but will remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole.

I think this will not include new packages automatically that are included into the image of the new version so you may install them if you want. But you haven't needed them before otherwise they were upgraded. To be really sure that you have all new features you have to compare with the [Release Notes](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/release_notes.txt).

Comment: ```full-upgrade``` is a synonym for ```dist-upgrade```. It runs exactly the same process on Raspbian.

Comment: @Dougie Thanks for clarification. I was unsure because `apt` has commands which are not covered by `apt-get`, `apt-cache`.