# How to check the Raspian version installed?

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch

How do I check the version of Raspian I currently have installed? I would imagine that it is Stretch but would like to verify that.

Answer (score 3):

You can install lsb_release if you don't have it and run:

```
lsb_release -a
```

if you are looking for kernel info:

```
 uname -a
```

or you can do this:

```
cat /etc/os-release
```