# Howto tell the difference between a RP3B and RP4B from a script?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, script, pi-4

I want to create scripts that configure RP3 and RP4 software installations using Raspbian Lite.
The scripts need to know the difference between an RP3B+ and and RP4B.

How can I do that?

Dazz

Comment: See [What OS version is installed]](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/85016/8697) You can also have different setting in `config.txt`

Comment: I am seeking to find out the hardware version, not the OS version.

Comment: Did you actually read the link?

Comment: I was about to add that I see the Model can be read.    You beat me to it.