# I am unable to upgrade Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: raspbian

I got my Pi in Fall, 2018, and have not had trouble running it. However, when I tried to upgrade my Raspbian back in May, 2019, and it didn’t look like I succeeded because when I issued the command “cat /etc/rpi-issue”, the response was:

Raspberry Pi reference 2018-06-27
Generated using pi-gen, https://github.com/Rpi-Distro/pi-gen,
 0d34fb94398a4bd79711f21d6a0b5d35fe5f4a76, stage5

I assume the “reference” is to the “name” of the release and I knew there were releases subsequent to June, 2018.

I got distracted and didn’t try again until today. After several attempts, I’m pretty sure I got the list of updates (sudo apt update) but during “sudo apt dist-upgrade”, my Verizon connection dropped. Even though I did a reboot (sudo reboot), my reference is still June, 2018, no packages download (sudo apt update) and nothing changes with sudo apt dist-upgrade.

What can I do to get the updates to be applied?

Thank you for any help.
Diane

Answer (score 1):

The Reference is the initial download installed.

It never changes and has nothing to do with current OS.

See [What OS version is installed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85015/what-os-version-is-installed) if you want to know what you currently have.