# Get raspberry firmware version

Tags: firmware

I want to know what is my raspberry pi firmware version.

I have read some documentations and i have found 2 ways to get this version number:

```
/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd version
```

and

```
FIRMWARE_HASH=$(zgrep "* firmware as of" /usr/share/doc/raspberrypi-bootloader/changelog.Debian.gz | head -1 | awk '{ print $5 }')
```

This gives me 2 differents versions for the same raspberry pi.

What is the good command to get firmware version ?
What is the explaination of the other command ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are many ways to discover identifiers related to version. I don't pretend to understand what the script is dragging out.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/85016/8697 for all the information of any use.

The date reported in `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd version` is the only meaningful data - the others are useful only if you are trying to access the git archives.

```
Sep  2 2020 21:13:13 
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version 4439d2aaa6c376a2d1ef4402f142e1cf4de37c43 (clean) (release) (start)
```