# How can I determine which model Raspberry Pi I am running?

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, pi-zero

I have several RPi's on my network.  How do I figure out what model any given RPi is?

Comment: After checking, I agree that this is a duplicate and that https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61699/is-there-a-bash-command-to-check-if-the-raspberry-pi-is-2-or-3 has better answers.  Its only flaw is that the title is too restrictive and doesn't handle (e.g.) Pi Zero.  I'll edit its title and delete this one.

Comment: When I tried to delete this post, I got ominous warnings from SO, especially since it's already gotten several upvotes.  So I guess it stays for now.

Answer (score 4):

From a shell window, type `cat /proc/device-tree/model`.  For example:

```
$ cat /proc/device-tree/model
Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
```